# Missing 'Default Components' tab in test plan

Tags: kiwi-tcms

New to Kiwi TCMS and running through tutorial.

In https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/testplan.html#default-components, it explains a 'Default Components' tab in test plan. Problem is, the tab is missing in our Kiwi setup. Cannot find related steps in documentation about this either.

Is there a setting/process not discussed in documentation to enable it?

Comment: @prome is right, this has been removed. Documentation & screenshot has remained stale. The entire section should be removed. Pull requests are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed in:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/commit/09321236ee2ecbdfc2d001a0e1e28b0504c30171

> Remove TestPlan components functionality
>
> this functionality was never used and never intended to be used in
>   such a way. Components are something that is attached to test cases
>   not test plans!