# How do you associate a Component to a Test Case?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

According to the [response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747294/missing-default-components-tab-in-test-plan/59748668#59748668), Components can be associated with Test Cases. However, I don't see any field present in the Test Case edit form for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Components are only visible on View test case page and unfortunately not also on Edit test case page.

Example from their demo application - https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/case/8681/

[image]